# Prove that $f \ \text{surjective} \iff f(b_1),...,f(b_n) \ \text{generating system of} \ W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $n \in N$, $V$ and $W$ be $K$ vector spaces, $f: V \to W$ linear, $b_1,...,b_n$ basis of $V$

How to show that the following equivalence holds true?

$f \ \text{surjective} \iff f(b_1),...,f(b_n) \ \text{generating system of} \ W$

Comment: Answering this question comes down to manipulating the definitions.  What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried? Do you understand what it means for $f$ to be surjective?  Do you understand what it means for a set of vectors to form a generating system?

Comment: In the context of a vector space, a generating system is equivalent to a *spanning set*.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Surjective means that there is at least one corresponding value in W for every value in V. Generating system means its vectors are linear independent and you can reach every value in W by multiplying and adding up the vectors of the generating system.

Comment: Both of your definitions are incorrect.  Surjective means that there is at least one vector in $V$ which produces any every vector in $W$ (you had the spaces reversed), and a generating system does not need to be linearly independent.

Comment: Do you understand Bernard's answer?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Not quite. I know that a basis is the smallest generating system, so coming from the preconditions it makes sense. But how can I actually use that in order to show the equivalence to f being surjective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $f(b_1),\dots,f(b_n)$ is a generating system.  We want to show that for any $y$, there is an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Start with such a $y$. Using our supposition, there exist coefficents $c_1,\dots,c_n$ such that $c_1 f(b_1) + \cdots + c_nf(b_n) = y$.  The "information" that we obtained from the vector $y$ is the set of coefficients $c_1,\dots,c_n$.  How can we use these coefficients to build the vector $x$ that we want?  Even more vaguely: what is an easy way to use these coefficients to build a vector $x \in V$? 
Once we figure that out, we'll have proven one direction.

Conversely, suppose that $f$ is surjective. Let $y \in W$ be arbitrary. We want to show that there exist coefficients such that $c_1f(b_1) + \cdots + c_n f(b_n) = y$.  Try to follow the same kind of process.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

For any $f$, if $\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, $\;\{f(b_1),\dots,f(b_n)\}$ is a generating set of $f(V)$.